# How to remove seq of array elments matching a pattern at the beginning and the end?

Tags: jq

Suppose that I have a json file, in which the following pattern appears many times.

```
... [ ... ["X"], ... ,["Y"] ... ] ...
```

I want to remove everything between each pair of `["X"]` and `["Y"]`. How can I do it?

Comment: Use the first "Y".

Comment: Okay, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to have two components:

(1) Given an array, how can I delete all segments that are "bookended" by two values?

(2) Given a single JSON entity (aka document), how can I perform the above-mentioned deletion operation on all arrays, no matter where they occur within the document?

Here, I will offer an alternative to @pmf's solution for (1) and show how to apply it to an entire JSON entity.

Here's the alternative, which has the possible advantage that it doesn't make any strong assumptions about the occurrence of the $x and $y values, and allows for both interpretations regarding the removal of the bookends themselves:

```
# Input: an array
# Remove all stretches from $x to the next $y,
# removing both bookends too if and only if $bookends.
# Both bookends must be present for a stretch to be removed.
def remove_all_xy($x; $y; $bookends):
  # The helper function removes a single stretch from $x to $y, if any
  def r:
    index($x) as $ix
    | if $ix then .[$ix+1:] as $tail
      | ($tail | index($y)) as $iy
      | if $iy  
        then (if $bookends then 0 else 1 end) as $adjust
        | .[:$ix + $adjust] + ($tail | .[1+$iy - $adjust:] | r)
        else . end
      else . end;
  r;
```

Now let's say you decide on some function, `foo($x;$y;$bookends)`, for performing the per-array operation.  To apply it to the whole document,
you could write:

```
walk(if type == "array" then foo($x;$y;$bookends) else . end)
```

This might not be as efficient as possible, but in practice it should suffice.  (If not, then simply adapt the standard `walk`.)

Comment: Your innermost `if` with condition `$iy` seems to be tautological, as it is part of the `then` branch of a parent `if` with the same condition. Also, you might be right regarding your interpretation of where (and where not) the bookends "can appear in any context". I was probably overthinking it by reaching for `paths` and `tostream`, assuming that any two corresponding ends may also independently appear in different constructs and/or on different levels. But your grasp of it seems far more reasonable.

Comment: @pmf - Tx. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pairwise occurrences, and that "between" means excluding the border items, you could query the `indices` of the border items, and fetch everything in between.

Given the following sample, the following filter will produce the following output:

```json
[
  ["A"], ["B"], ["X"], ["C"], ["D"], ["Y"], ["E"], ["F"],
  ["G"], ["H"], ["X"], ["I"], ["J"], ["Y"], ["K"], ["L"]
]
```

```bash
[
  (
    [[indices([["X"]]), indices([["Y"]])] | 0, transpose[][], infinite]
    | _nwise(2)
  )
  as [$a, $b] | .[$a:$b+1][]
]
```

```json
[["A"],["B"],["X"],["Y"],["E"],["F"],["G"],["H"],["X"],["Y"],["K"],["L"]]
```

---

If the border items may occur in any order, and not necessarily in equal amounts, before transposing the two lists of indices they would need to be filtered first to only contain mutually successive positions.

Comment: Are you assuming the whole input is an array? In my question, the subarray to be deleted can appear in any context. That is why I think this problem is very hard. I don't even know how to start with.

Comment: @user1424739 Then please elaborate on "any context" in your question, ideally by providing a concrete working example that I can test my approach against.

Comment: It can be anything. For example, it can be in an element of dictionary, that dictionary can be in another array, that array can be in a dictionary. The possibility is endless, there is no way for me to enumerate all of them. The moment that I specify an example, it will make people think that my question is specific to that specific situation. But that is not my intention.

Comment: @user1424739 But you should be able to give *some* working examples. Make them as diverse as possible, and there's a fair chance that you will get a solution as universal as you have envisioned - or point out then what's missing. But in the current state with no useful examples whatsoever I can't do anything else but guessing (as it was the case, for instance, with how to handle which kind of reccurrence of the border items, or whether they should be removed as well or not, etc.). Examples (input and output), even not being exhaustive, **do** help immensely.

Comment: @user1424739 For the time being, with the vague constraint of "anything", you may want to have a look at the `tostream` [filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tostream) (or its `--stream` [option](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) equivalent) which give you a stream of path-value pairs to process, or at the `paths/1` [filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#paths%2Cpaths%28node_filter%29%2Cleaf_paths) which emits paths based on a node filter without the hassle of backtracking items that come with `tostream`. With more examples I'll be glad to dive into that.

Comment: Thanks. But at this moment, it is very hard for me to figure it out from real examples. The real examples are too complex for me to find out a reasonable subset that preserves the essential structure without losing its key features.

Comment: @user1424739 Alright, may you be successful in your explorations! In the meantime, consider "deleting" your question (as it is quite unanswerable atm), and undelete it again once you have succeeded in constraining your question with further details.